# How to switch to last-used workspace in Ubuntu 20.04, Gnome 3.36?

Tags: gnome-shell, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I know the keyboard shortcuts to switch to the next/previous/last workspaces.

What I can't find is a shortcut to switch back to the last workspace I've visited.

A way to navigate the history of workspaces I visited, like back/forward buttons in a browser.

For example, I work in workspace A. Then a message comes in in Slack. I click on the notification. This throws me to the workspace where I put Slack. I finish my business on Slack, and want to go back to where I was before.

Is there a way to traverse like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already installed: `<Super>Tab` switches to last used window. If you visited only one window on the current workspace, the last used window is on the last used workspace.

Better solution:

- install the gnome extension
  https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1089/go-to-last-workspace/
- change workspace twice (to fill the workspace history)
- you can now switch to last used workspace with `<Super>escape`.
  If you want to change this binding, see comment by cyberalex4life
  or the readme on the extension homepage: https://github.com/arjan/gnome-shell-go-to-last-workspace